# Why doesn't AVPlayer stop loading data?

Tags: ios, ios7, avplayer

When I watch my mac's network connectivity I can tell that a movie is still buffering even after I remove the view which had the AVPlayer on it.

Does anyone know how to force AVPlayer to stop loading data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out.

When you want to stop an AVPlayerItem from loading, use AVQueuePlayer's removeAllItems and then re-initialize it.

```
  [self.avPlayer removeAllItems];
  self.avPlayer = [AVQueuePlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
  self.avPlayer = nil;
```

This will stop the current item from loading -- it is the only way I found to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's late to answer this question, but I've just solved the same one.
Just save here in case anyone need...

```
    [self.player.currentItem cancelPendingSeeks];
    [self.player.currentItem.asset cancelLoading];
```

There's no cancel method in `AVPlayer` class, but in `AVPlayerItem` and `AVAsset` class, there are!

PS: `player` here is `AVPlayer` class, not `AVQueuePlayer` class.

Answer (score 0):

An AVPlayer is not a view. You may have "removed the view" but that does not mean you have removed or stopped the AVPlayer. I would guess that the way to do what you want is to destroy the AVPlayer itself.

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking how to destroy it. It has no teardown methods as far as I can tell, and setting my avplayer reference to nil doesn't do it either. When I said "after I remove the view" I actually meant "after I remove the viewcontroller that it's in".  Pausing it doesn't work, either.